# Shorthand IF Statement

Tags: javascript

I'm curious, is there a simpler way to say

```
if(myVar == myVal || myVar == myOtherVal){ /*...*/ }
```

such as:

```
if(myVar == myVal || myOtherVal){ /* */ }
```

I am aware that my proposed code only checkes to see whether `myVar` equals `myVal` or `myOtherVal` is not `null` (undefined) and `false`.

So, as I stated before, is there a simpler way to write

```
if(myVar == myVal || myVar == myOtherVal){ /*...*/ }
```

Just curious to know if there's some sort of jS shorthand `if` statment that works like this that I have missed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a good example of "more clever != better", I think. :)

Comment: `myVar == myVal || myVar == myOtherVal` is the standard and idiomatic way of implementing your logic. Trying to do it any other is just going to be confusing and buggy and will make the people (possibly you) that maintain your code hate you.

Comment: I was just looking for a shorter way to do this when comparing one variable against a bunch of others. And what? I love myself. Although occasionally I turn myself down to keep it interesting.

Comment: That comment you just made(one variable against a bunch of others), if written in your question, could have saved me a lot of grief.  Sheesh =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for. http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/testing_for_a_v

Comment: I like your and @minitech's answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use arrays:

```
if([myVal, myOtherVal].indexOf(myVar) + 1) { /* or > -1 or !== -1 */ }
```

Or `switch` statements:

```
switch(myVar) {
     case myVal:
     case myOtherVal:
          /* */
          break;
}
```

These only really apply when comparing the variable to more than two possible values, though.

Comment: I'd prefer `[...].indexOf(myVar) != -1` though. Took me a second to realize that this even works.

Comment: I sure hope he isn't *that* desperate ;)

Comment: Yes, I hope so too :) Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

You could use the `Array`'s `indexOf` with an array if you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

```
result = ((myVar==myval)||(myVar==myOtherVal)) ? x : y;
```

Can be:

```
if((myVar==myVal) || (myVar==myOtherVal))
   result = x;
else
   result = y;
```

Also:

```
((myVar==myval)||(myVar==myOtherVal)) ? someFunction() : otherFunction();
```

Is the same as:

```
if((myVar==myVal) || (myVar==myOtherVal))
    someFunction();
else
    otherFunction();
```

Comment: Be careful though, the ternary operator can be confusing (even for seasoned developers) in all but the simplest of cases...

Comment: That..doesn't work. It does basically what I underlined above...maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Maybe I'm the one who's missing something but the code I gave you is pretty much the same as your examples?  I just changed it so that it did something other than /*...*/ for illustration.

Comment: The method he suggests doesn't do what you want, or, you can't get it working? Works fine for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/4kQLH/ One word of advice though, should be using `===` instead of `==`, might not matter a whole lot in this case, but it's better to get used to using three than two.

Comment: Um, "obfuscated" and "simple" are different words. And your logic is incorrect, it assigns `x` to `result` if `myVar` is equal to `myval` or if `myOtherVal` is true.

Comment: @muistooshort: It's only obfuscated to those who don't understand it.

Comment: @Shaz: Try your fiddle with `myVar=0` and `myOtherVal=0`. Ahem.

Comment: @muistooshort Is that really what you are going on about?  Of course myOtherVal = 0 will cause it to be false.  I dunno but that seems like a moot point.  What is the issue with that?

Comment: I meant, it does what my initial example does, but uses more code and is not shorthand-y.

Comment: @Pete: The question is about `myVar == myVal || myVar == myOtherVal`, Pete's expressions don't do anything like that so his logic is incorrect. `0 == 3 || 0 == 0` is true but `(0 == 3)||(0)` is false. Nice to see that both you and Shaz have fixed your logic errors during the discussion though.

Comment: @nexxeus If you want more "shorthand-y" get shorter variable names.  The ternary operator uses a "?" for the if and a ":" for the else.  So that's 6 keystrokes down to 2.  By definition that is shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use && as a "guard":

```
(myVar == myVal || myVar == myOtherVal) && /* expression */
```

But I don't recommend it. Your code should be easily read and maintained, so:

```
if (myVar == myVal || myVar == myOtherVal) {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

is much better to me.